# Creating counter inside a string in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0, xls

How to create incremental counter using newline or string inside element? We have this value on my xml

```
<root>
<text>One
Two
Three
Four
Five
</text>
</root>
```

Expected template:

```
<xsl:template match="root">

<xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
<xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat(text, $delimiter))" />

<xsl:if test="$token">
<xsl:value-of select="my-count-here"/> <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Expected Result:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
4 Four
5 Five
```

the node "my-count-here" are the counter and use it as an id. Could any one know how to implement this?

Comment: What is the expected result??

Comment: Sorry suppose to be a condition to  add a variable to call as a counter

Comment: You are not answering my question: what is the expected output from running the template you propose? IOW, what is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Please see updates on my question. I just need to add an Id on each string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you show can be produced by applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note (1) the use of a *named* template and (2) the recursive call. Both are missing from your attempt.